# breakout collision detection

Tags: javascript, collision, detection, breakout

I'm coding a Breakout game with Javascript. I took the MDN tutorial and another tutorial and I'm trying to modify the original with a OOP approach. Until now, everything works fine except for the collision detection with the paddle. Which is not happening. Why is that? Here's my code. Can somebody help? Thanks!

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('game');
var theLoop;
var paddleSpeed = 4;

//OBJECTS
//Game
function Game() {
  this.width = canvas.width;
  this.height = canvas.height;
  this.ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  this.ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  this.p = new Paddle(0, 130);
  this.p.x = (this.width - this.p.width) / 2;
  this.keys = new Keylistener();
  this.ball = new Ball();
  this.ball.x = this.width / 2;
  this.ball.y = 125;
  this.ball.vy = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12 - 6);  
  this.ball.vx = 7 - Math.abs(this.ball.vy);
}

Game.prototype.draw = function() {
  this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
  this.p.draw(this.ctx);
  this.ball.draw(this.ctx);
};

Game.prototype.update = function() {
  if (this.paused) return;
  this.ball.update();
  //Right Paddle's Directions
  if (this.keys.isPressed(37)) { // LEFT
    this.p.x = Math.max(0, this.p.x - paddleSpeed);
  } else if (this.keys.isPressed(39)) { // RIGHT
        
    this.p.x = Math.min(this.p.x + paddleSpeed, this.width - this.p.width);
  }


  if (this.ball.x < this.ball.ballRadius || this.ball.x > this.width - this.ball.ballRadius) { //LEFT & RIGHT
    this.ball.vx = -this.ball.vx;
  }
  if (this.ball.y < this.ball.ballRadius) { //TOP
    this.ball.vy = -this.ball.vy;
  } else if (this.ball.y > this.height - this.ball.ballRadius) {
    if (this.ball.x > this.p.x && this.ball.x < this.p.x + this.p.width) {
      this.ball.vy = -this.ball.vy;
      console.log('hit');
    } else {
      //      console.log(this.ball.x);
    }
  }
};

/////Paddle
function Paddle(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.width = 30;
  this.height = 5;
  this.score = 0;
}

Paddle.prototype.draw = function(p) {
  p.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
};

///KEY LISTENER
function Keylistener() {
  this.pressedKeys = [];
  this.keydown = function(e) {
    this.pressedKeys[e.keyCode] = true;
  };
  this.keyup = function(e) {
    this.pressedKeys[e.keyCode] = false;
  };
  document.addEventListener("keydown", this.keydown.bind(this));
  document.addEventListener("keyup", this.keyup.bind(this));
}

Keylistener.prototype.isPressed = function(key) {
  return this.pressedKeys[key] ? true : false;
};

Keylistener.prototype.addKeyPressListener = function(keyCode, callback) {
  document.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == keyCode) callback(e);
  });
};

///BALL
function Ball() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
  this.vx = 0;
  this.vy = 0;
  this.ballRadius = 5;
}

Ball.prototype.update = function() {
  this.x += this.vx;
  this.y += this.vy;
};

Ball.prototype.draw = function(p) {
  p.beginPath();
  p.arc(this.x, this.y, this.ballRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  p.fill();
  p.closePath();
};


//Initialize the game
var game = new Game();

//the Main Engine
function mainLoop() {
  theLoop = setInterval(function() {
    game.update();
    game.draw();
  }, 33.3333);
}

//calling the Main Engine
mainLoop();
```

```css
#game {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #353535;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="game"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('game');
var theLoop;
var paddleSpeed = 4;

//OBJECTS
//Game
function Game() {
  this.width = canvas.width;
  this.height = canvas.height;
  this.ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  this.ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  this.p = new Paddle(0, 130);
  this.p.x = (this.width - this.p.width) / 2;
  this.keys = new Keylistener();
  this.ball = new Ball();
  this.ball.x = this.width / 2;
  this.ball.y = 125;
  this.ball.vy = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12 - 6);  
  this.ball.vx = 7 - Math.abs(this.ball.vy);
}

Game.prototype.draw = function() {
  this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
  this.p.draw(this.ctx);
  this.ball.draw(this.ctx);
};

Game.prototype.update = function() {
  if (this.paused) return;
  this.ball.update();
  //Right Paddle's Directions
  if (this.keys.isPressed(37)) { // LEFT
    this.p.x = Math.max(0, this.p.x - paddleSpeed);
  } else if (this.keys.isPressed(39)) { // RIGHT
        
    this.p.x = Math.min(this.p.x + paddleSpeed, this.width - this.p.width);
  }


  if (this.ball.x < this.ball.ballRadius || this.ball.x > this.width - this.ball.ballRadius) { //LEFT & RIGHT
    this.ball.vx = -this.ball.vx;
  }
  if (this.ball.y < this.ball.ballRadius) { //TOP
    this.ball.vy = -this.ball.vy;
  } else if (this.ball.y > this.p.y - this.ball.ballRadius && 
            this.ball.y < this.p.y + this.p.height + this.ball.ballRadius) {

   if (this.ball.x > this.p.x && this.ball.x < this.p.x + this.p.width) {
      this.ball.vy = -this.ball.vy;
      console.log('hit');
    } else {
      //      console.log(this.ball.x);
    }
  }
};

/////Paddle
function Paddle(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.width = 30;
  this.height = 5;
  this.score = 0;
}

Paddle.prototype.draw = function(p) {
  p.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
};

///KEY LISTENER
function Keylistener() {
  this.pressedKeys = [];
  this.keydown = function(e) {
    this.pressedKeys[e.keyCode] = true;
  };
  this.keyup = function(e) {
    this.pressedKeys[e.keyCode] = false;
  };
  document.addEventListener("keydown", this.keydown.bind(this));
  document.addEventListener("keyup", this.keyup.bind(this));
}

Keylistener.prototype.isPressed = function(key) {
  return this.pressedKeys[key] ? true : false;
};

Keylistener.prototype.addKeyPressListener = function(keyCode, callback) {
  document.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == keyCode) callback(e);
  });
};

///BALL
function Ball() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
  this.vx = 0;
  this.vy = 0;
  this.ballRadius = 5;
}

Ball.prototype.update = function() {
  this.x += this.vx;
  this.y += this.vy;
};

Ball.prototype.draw = function(p) {
  p.beginPath();
  p.arc(this.x, this.y, this.ballRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  p.fill();
  p.closePath();
};


//Initialize the game
var game = new Game();

//the Main Engine
function mainLoop() {
  theLoop = setInterval(function() {
    game.update();
    game.draw();
  }, 33.3333);
}

//calling the Main Engine
mainLoop();
```

```css
#game {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #353535;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="game"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this section right here.

```
else if (this.ball.y > this.height - this.ball.ballRadius) {
    if (this.ball.x > this.p.x && this.ball.x < this.p.x + this.p.width) {
```

You aren't trying to register a hit with the paddle unless the ball is at the bottom of the screen. You need to be checking if the ball intersects with the paddle *before* you hit the bottom of the screen.

```
var paddleLeft = this.p.x;
var paddleRight = paddleLeft + this.p.width;
var paddleTop = this.p.y;
var ballLeft = this.ball.x;
var ballRight = ballLeft + this.ball.ballRadius;
var ballBottom = this.ball.y + this.ball.ballRadius;
var xCollision = (ballLeft <= paddleRight && ballRight >= paddleLeft);
var yCollision = (ballBottom >= paddleTop);
if (this.ball.y < this.ball.ballRadius) { //TOP
  this.ball.vy = -this.ball.vy;
} else if (xCollision && yCollision) {
  this.ball.vy = -this.ball.vy;
  console.log('hit');
}
```

Here it is running in your game.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('game');
var theLoop;
var paddleSpeed = 4;

//OBJECTS
//Game
function Game() {
  this.width = canvas.width;
  this.height = canvas.height;
  this.ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  this.ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  this.p = new Paddle(0, 220);
  this.p.x = (this.width - this.p.width) / 2;
  this.keys = new Keylistener();
  this.ball = new Ball();
  this.ball.x = this.width / 2;
  this.ball.y = 125;
  this.ball.vy = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12 - 6);  
  this.ball.vx = 7 - Math.abs(this.ball.vy);
}

Game.prototype.draw = function() {
  this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
  this.p.draw(this.ctx);
  this.ball.draw(this.ctx);
};

Game.prototype.update = function() {
  if (this.paused) return;
  this.ball.update();
  //Right Paddle's Directions
  if (this.keys.isPressed(37)) { // LEFT
    this.p.x = Math.max(0, this.p.x - paddleSpeed);
  } else if (this.keys.isPressed(39)) { // RIGHT
        
    this.p.x = Math.min(this.p.x + paddleSpeed, this.width - this.p.width);
  }

  var leftBallCollision = this.ball.x < this.ball.ballRadius;
  var rightBallCollision = this.ball.x > this.width - this.ball.ballRadius;
  if (leftBallCollision || rightBallCollision) { //LEFT & RIGHT
    this.ball.vx = -this.ball.vx;
  }
  
  var paddleLeft = this.p.x;
  var paddleRight = paddleLeft + this.p.width;
  var paddleTop = this.p.y;
  var ballLeft = this.ball.x;
  var ballRight = ballLeft + this.ball.ballRadius;
  var ballBottom = this.ball.y + this.ball.ballRadius;
  var xCollision = (ballLeft <= paddleRight && ballRight >= paddleLeft);
  var yCollision = (ballBottom >= paddleTop);
  if (this.ball.y < this.ball.ballRadius) { //TOP
    this.ball.vy = -this.ball.vy;
  } else if (xCollision && yCollision) {
    this.ball.vy = -this.ball.vy;
    console.log('hit');
  }
};

/////Paddle
function Paddle(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.width = 30;
  this.height = 5;
  this.score = 0;
}

Paddle.prototype.draw = function(p) {
  p.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
};

///KEY LISTENER
function Keylistener() {
  this.pressedKeys = [];
  this.keydown = function(e) {
    this.pressedKeys[e.keyCode] = true;
  };
  this.keyup = function(e) {
    this.pressedKeys[e.keyCode] = false;
  };
  document.addEventListener("keydown", this.keydown.bind(this));
  document.addEventListener("keyup", this.keyup.bind(this));
}

Keylistener.prototype.isPressed = function(key) {
  return this.pressedKeys[key] ? true : false;
};

Keylistener.prototype.addKeyPressListener = function(keyCode, callback) {
  document.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == keyCode) callback(e);
  });
};

///BALL
function Ball() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
  this.vx = 0;
  this.vy = 0;
  this.ballRadius = 5;
}

Ball.prototype.update = function() {
  this.x += this.vx;
  this.y += this.vy;
};

Ball.prototype.draw = function(p) {
  p.beginPath();
  p.arc(this.x, this.y, this.ballRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  p.fill();
  p.closePath();
};


//Initialize the game
var game = new Game();

//the Main Engine
function mainLoop() {
  theLoop = setInterval(function() {
    game.update();
    game.draw();
  }, 33.3333);
}

//calling the Main Engine
mainLoop();
```

```css
#game {
  background-color: #353535;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="game" width="320" height="240"></canvas>
```